# Select run time temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario where i need to pull a temp table data at run time in 1 select sql query. The below does not work. Any advise?

```
 select * from   
  (
     insert into #temp3   
     select * from GetOrgs('14090',0,1)  
  )
```

Comment: First insert the data in temp table then fetch the  data from table

Comment: That will work. But i need to have it in 1 select SQL statement.

Comment: then why are you inserting data in temp table fir fetch the proper data from select statement then insert into temp table

Comment: I am not sure, that this will be possible. But most close solution to what you are looking is create stored procedure

Comment: @SaharshShah, the reason is because i have a complex query which i need to turn the existing table into a temp table first under 1 select query.

Comment: What is your DBMS and its version?

Comment: @Kaf, SQLserver 2012

Comment: @belinq Then you have to try some other way to resolve your problem. You can also check fer CTE expression in sql server, I hope that will resolve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OUTPUT` clause with `INSERTED` to insert and select using a single query.

```
INSERT INTO #temp3 (col1, col2,...)
OUTPUT INSERTED.col1, INSERTED.col2, ...
SELECT c1, c2, ...
FROM yourTable
...
```

**[Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23506)**